# Highlighting different features in layer with different colors in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to highlight two features in a layer with two colors at the same time.

This is my highlight function:

```
def highlight_selection(self, color, results):
    """
    Highlight the selection on the canvas.  This updates all selected objects based on the result set.
    :param results: A dict-of-list of layer-features.
    """
    #self.clear_selection()
    for layer, features in results:#.items():
        print(layer)
        print(features)
        band = self.selectionbands[layer]
        print(band)
        band.setColor(color)
        band.setIconSize(25)
        band.setWidth(5)
        band.setBrushStyle(Qt.NoBrush)
        band.reset(layer.geometryType())
        band.setZValue(self.currentfeatureband.zValue() - 1)
        for feature in features:
            band.addGeometry(feature.geometry(), layer)
    #self.canvas.update()
```

when I use code below to highlight different features,

```
highlight_selection(mapwin, QColor(0, 255, 0), getFeatures(city1))
highlight_selection(mapwin, QColor(255, 0, 0), getFeatures(city2))
```

only city2 can be highlighted.
So, I'm confused.